# How does python's SimpleHTTPServer do_GET and do_POST functions work?

Tags: python, server, simplehttpserver

I've created the following little HTTP server for learning purposes:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

class ServerHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        print(self.headers)
        SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

    def do_POST(self):
        print(self.headers)
        form = cgi.FieldStorage(
            fp=self.rfile,
            headers=self.headers,
            environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                 'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],

def main():
    port = 50738
    Handler = ServerHandler(1000)
    httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("192.168.X.Y", port), Handler)

    print "serving at port", port
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My assumptions are as follows:

- My class 'ServerHandler' extends the SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler class by two functions namely go_GET and do_POST
- The main() function creates a server handler object and server socket bound to my I.P. address and port of choice, and invokes a function to serve/listen indefinitely.

**Aside**: I know by looking at the Python DOCs https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html that SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler has a method  called do_GET, which I assume gets overridden by the do_GET in my ServerHandler class?

**Question**:
What is going on under the hood relating to do_GET and do_POST? Is it the case that once we have this server listening for HTTP "activity" directed towards a specific IP:PORT that it automatically know if an incoming signal is a GET or POST and as soon as one is encountered the server calls my do_GET or do_POST functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `SocketServer.TCPServer`, you assign your `Handler` class as the class to receive incoming requests.

All that the `SimpleHTTPServer` module has helped you with is providing the basic HTTP functionality, but you could write all of that yourself.

So, as you say, when you define `Handler`, you are inheriting all the methods from the `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` class, but then overriding two of the pre-defined methods: `do_GET` and `do_POST`. You could also override any other methods in the class.

However, these `do_*` methods would *never* be called if it wasn't for the `handle` method defined in the `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` as it is this function which *is* called by the `socketserver` module.

So if you were to just inherit the `socketserver.BaseRequestHandler`, you would loose all functionality as this class' `handle()` method does nothing:

> **`class socketserver.BaseRequestHandler`**
>
> ...
>
> `handle()`
>
> > This function must do all the work required to service a
> >     request. The default implementation does nothing. Several instance
> >     attributes are available to it; the request is available as
> >     self.request; the client address as self.client_address; and the
> >     server instance as self.server, in case it needs access to per-server
> >     information.
>
> ...

So, by importing the `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` from the `SimpleHTTPServer` module, you immediately get the basic functionality for a HTTP server.

All this functionality is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler), with an important bit on its `handle` method:

> **`class http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler(request, client_address, server)`**
>
> ...
>
> `handle()`
>
> > Calls handle_one_request() once (or, if persistent
> >     connections are enabled, multiple times) to handle incoming HTTP
> >     requests. You should never need to override it; instead, implement
> >     appropriate do_*() methods.
>
> `handle_one_request()`
>
> > **This method will parse and dispatch the request
> >     to the appropriate do_*() method.** You should never need to override
> >     it.
>
> ...

So finally, after breaking down how the `socketserver.TCPServer` will call the `handle()` method for *whatever* class you pass it, we see how the `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` implements this as passing the request onto the appropriate `do_GET`, `do_POST` or whatever method depending on the headers of the request.

---

If you want to see how you could implement this yourself, take a look at the source code, either in `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/http/server.py` or on [GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/http/server.py).

We can see there what their that `SimpleHTTPServer` inherits `BaseHTTPServer` which is where the `handle()` and `handle_one_request()` methods are defined:

So, as the docs describe, `handle` just passes requests to `handle_one_request` until the connection closes:

```
def handle(self):
    """Handle multiple requests if necessary."""
    self.close_connection = True

    self.handle_one_request()
    while not self.close_connection:
        self.handle_one_request()
```

and the `handle_one_request` is where the `do_*` methods get called:

```
def handle_one_request(self):
    """Handle a single HTTP request.
    You normally don't need to override this method; see the class
    __doc__ string for information on how to handle specific HTTP
    commands such as GET and POST.
    """
    try:
        self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
        if len(self.raw_requestline) > 65536:
            self.requestline = ''
            self.request_version = ''
            self.command = ''
            self.send_error(HTTPStatus.REQUEST_URI_TOO_LONG)
            return
        if not self.raw_requestline:
            self.close_connection = True
            return
        if not self.parse_request():
            # An error code has been sent, just exit
            return
        mname = 'do_' + self.command   ## the name of the method is created
        if not hasattr(self, mname):   ## checking that we have that method defined
            self.send_error(
                HTTPStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED,
                "Unsupported method (%r)" % self.command)
            return
        method = getattr(self, mname)  ## getting that method
        method()                       ## finally calling it
        self.wfile.flush() #actually send the response if not already done.
    except socket.timeout as e:
        #a read or a write timed out.  Discard this connection
        self.log_error("Request timed out: %r", e)
        self.close_connection = True
        return
```

*(note, I double-hashed (`##`) my comments to seperate them from the original author's)*

Comment: @ Joe lddon - Thank you, that is a fantastic answer. I understand now. Unfortunately my user rating is not enough to up-vote this answer. Thanks again